# How to loop through nested Firebase keys in Polymer

Tags: polymer, firebase-polymer

So, I have a Polymer project that is saving to Firebase. My data looks like this:

[image]

What I'm trying to do is loop through the `teams` property in the data. Considering Polymer only loops through Arrays right now, this is proving to be pretty challenging (since Firebase preferably returns data as objects). So far, I can loop through the `keys` and get the `teams`, but can't get into the `teams` to loop through it. Here is my code:

```
<template repeat="{{key in keys}}">
   <div class="tile">
       <paper-shadow z="2" class="card" animated>
           <div id="header" class="header"></div>

            <div class="content">
              <p>{{data[key]}}</p>
              <span>{{team.club}}</span>
            </div>

            <footer horizontal layout>
              <paper-button id="teamview" on-tap="{{viewTeam}}" flex>VIEW</paper-button>
              <span flex></span>
              <paper-button id="teamDelete" on-tap="{{deleteTeam}}">DELETE</paper-button>
              <paper-button id="teamEdit" on-tap="{{editTeam}}">EDIT</paper-button>
            </footer>
        </paper-shadow>
     </div>
 </template>
```

I feel like I've tried almost every scenerio. Every time I try and loop one more level with `repeat="{{team in key}}"` it breaks. Seeing if maybe some one else has a better perspective on this? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, the way I found out needs more in-depth explaining regarding Polymer and Firebase. First off, when you enter your `location` attribute in the `firebase-element`, whenever you are sourcing your `data` and `keys`, it is specifically with *that* location - not your data as a whole.

Therefore, the problem I was having was rooted in my `location` attribute. Once I changed my location to specify the exact nested level I wanted to `push` and source data from - all was well. The end code looked like this:

```
<firebase-element id="fbase" 
   location="https://volleyball-app.firebaseio.com/{{user.uid}}/userTeams" 
   data="{{userTeams}}" keys="{{keys}}" dataReady="{{userReady}}">
</firebase-element>

<template repeat="{{key in keys}}">
  <div class="content">
    <p>{{userTeams[key]['team']}}</p>
    <span>{{userTeams[key]['club']}}</span>
  </div>
</template>
```

What this is doing is repeating through all the `keys` in the `<firebase-element id="fbase" 
   location="https://volleyball-app.firebaseio.com/{{user.uid}}/userTeams` location (nothing more). From there I'm grabbing the `team` property in each key.

Answer (score 0):

You need to bind the data, id and keys like this I think.

```html
<link rel="import" href="../polymer/polymer.html">
<link rel="import" href="../firebase-element/firebase-element.html">
 
<!--
Element providing solution to displaying value from firebase.
##### Example
    <firebase-repeat-element></firebase-repeat-element>
@element fb-repeat-element
@blurb Element providing solution to displaying value from firebase.
@status alpha
@homepage http://basicelements.github.io/firebase-repeat-element
-->
<polymer-element name="firebase-repeat-element" attributes="firebaseName">
  <template>
    <firebase-element location="https://{{firebaseName}}.firebaseio.com/members/{{id}}" data="{{data}}" keys="{{keys}}"></firebase-element>
    <template repeat="{{id in keys}}">
      <h2>{{data[id]['name']}}</h2>
      <img src="{{data[id]['image']}}">
    </template>
 
  </template>
  <script>
    Polymer({
      
    });
  </script>
</polymer-element>
```

Be free to fork it @https://gist.github.com/ed2ba06d5a16d11381d9.git